# Switch case not acting as expected - failing to evaluate case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

OKAY - Hands up if I'm a newbie to JS - Yup that's my hand up. so if someone could enlighten me as to what I've got wrong here i would be appreciative. its driving me spastic.

Have a webpage - it has a text box - I want to force it to only accept numbers. I know there are a lot of options out there but I want to be very very specific around what is a number and what is not - locale dependent. So I wrote some code I've used in other languages in JS. It is one of a few checker functions which are all failing in the same way.

```
1 function IsNumber( keyCode ){
2 //Allow numbers 0 to 9 and nothing else 
3   
4   // Ugly but adding zero forces the keyCode to be a number 
5   switch (keyCode + 0){  
6       case ( (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) ):
7           return true;
8       
9       default:
10          return false;
11  }
12}
```

keycode = 49, ASC_ZERO = 48,  ASC_NINE = 57

The code evaluates line 6 and drops through to line 10 when it should execute line 7

Google console checks out as me having all my ducks in a row so it should work.

Google console output.

```
>keyCode <= ASC_NINE
>true    
>keyCode >= ASC_ZERO
>true    
>true && true
>true    
>( (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) )
>true    
>(keyCode + 0)
>49    
>( (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) )
>true
```

I've double checked brackets, I think my semicolons are all correct.

Could I have done this as a series of if else statements - yes but in order to keep all my code consistent and because other checker functions have a number of cases I felt a Switch Case would be more maintainable.

Now I just want to know why it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

To recreate my problem enter a number in the first text field follow the event.

Total Testong Code here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<title>increment field</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// START OF DECLARATIONS

const ASC_UPPER_A = 65
const ASC_UPPER_Z = 90 
const ASC_LOWER_A = 97 
const ASC_LOWER_Z = 122
const ASC_ZERO = 48 
const ASC_NINE = 57 
const ASC_FULLSTOP = 46 
const ASC_NEGATIVE = 45 

const KEY_LEFT = 37 
const KEY_RIGHT = 39 
const KEY_UP = 38 
const KEY_DOWN = 40 
const KEY_DELETE = 46
const KEY_BACKSPACE= 8
const KEY_RETURN=13 
const KEY_TAB = 9 

const TYPE_IS_NUMERIC = 1
const TYPE_IS_NUMBER = 2
const TYPE_IS_ALPHA = 4
const TYPE_IS_DECIMAL = 8 
const TYPE_IS_INTEGER = 16
const TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE = 32 


// DECLARE HELPER FUNTIONS

function IsNumber( keyCode ){
//Allow numbers 0 to 9 and nothing else 

    // Ugly but adding zero forces the keyCode to be a number 
    switch (keyCode + 0){  
        case ( (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) ):
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function IsNumeric( keyCode ){
// We aren't using is_Numeric as it will 
// allow through e, ^, % and a couple of other chars    
//Check for NEGATIVE (-) & ASC_FULLSTOP (.) We don't allow comma (,) as it is not in the NZ locale  

    // Ugly but adding zero forces the keyCode to be a number 
    switch (keyCode + 0){  
        case IsNumber( keyCode ):
        case ASC_FULLSTOP:
        case ASC_NEGATIVE:
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

 function IsInteger( keyCode ){

    switch ( keyCode + 0){
        case IsNumber(keyCode): 
            return true;

        case ASC_NEGATIVE: 
            return true; // Negative integer 

        default: 
            return false;
    }
}

function IsAlpha( keyCode ){
// We aren't using ctype_alpha as it will allow through
// chars not in the NZ_Locale also numbers from -128 to 255
// are considered alpha of a single char 
// THIS TEST WILL ONLY WORK FOR SINGLE CHARS
    switch ( keyCode + 0){
        case (( keyCode >= ASC_LOWER_A ) && ( keyCode <= ASC_LOWER_Z ) ):
        case (( keyCode >= ASC_UPPER_A ) && ( keyCode <= ASC_UPPER_Z ) ):
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function IsWhiteSpace( keyCode ){

    switch ( keyCode + 0){
        case ( ASC_SPACE ):
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}


// Main function to test a if key stroke is valid
function AllowKey(e, keyType ) {
    var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode

        // If movement key then return without further tests
        switch( unicode){
            case  unicode >=KEY_LEFT && unicode <=KEY_DOWN:
            case KEY_DELETE:
            case KEY_BACKSPACE:
            case KEY_RETURN:
            case KEY_TAB:
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Test if unicode / keyCode  passes one of the tests 
        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_NUMERIC ) {
            if (IsNumeric( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }

        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_NUMBER ) {
            if (IsNumber( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }       

        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_ALPHA ) {
            if (IsAlpha( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }       

        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_DECIMAL ) {
            if (IsNumber( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }       

        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_INTEGER ) {
            if (IsInteger( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }       

        if ( keyType & TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE ) {
            if (IsWhiteSpace( unicode )){
                return true;
            }
        }       

        // If we have made it this far the unicode keystoke has failed the test 
        return false;
}



</script>

<form>
<p>
<label> TYPE_IS_NUMBER - 0 to 9 only </label>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeypress="return AllowKey(event, TYPE_IS_NUMBER )">
</p>
<p>
<label> TYPE_IS_NUMERIC - 0 to 9, - and . only </label>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeypress="return AllowKey(event, TYPE_IS_NUMERIC )">
</p>
<p>
<label> TYPE_IS_ALPHA ONLY a to z an A to Z only  </label>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeypress="return AllowKey(event, TYPE_IS_ALPHA )">
</p>
<p>
<label> TYPE_IS_ALPHA (a to z an A to Z ) and TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE ' " only  </label>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeypress="return AllowKey(event, TYPE_IS_ALPHA + TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE )">
</p>
<p>
<label> TYPE_IS_ALPHA (a to z an A to Z ) and TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE ' " & TYPE_IS_NUMERIC only  </label>
<input type="text" size=18 onkeypress="return AllowKey(event, TYPE_IS_ALPHA + TYPE_IS_WHITESPACE + TYPE_IS_NUMERIC)">
</p>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the value of (keyCode + 0) against  (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE)

like in

```
if( (keyCode + 0) == (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) )
```

so that's the error.

Comment: Maybe its a js thing but to my way of thinking - if :

Comment: Got it - My code breaks down to say  if 49 == true then ... which of course fails - I couldn't see it - thanks.  I've altered my code to say   switch(true) as per below       function IsNumber( keyCode ){  
    //Allow numbers 0 to 9 and nothing else   
 
    // Ugly but adding zero forces the keyCode to be a number   
    switch (true){    
  case ( (keyCode >= ASC_ZERO) && ( keyCode <= ASC_NINE) ):
   return true;
  
  default:
   return false;
 }
}